# How can I pass this state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I pass this state to my parent component?

I've tried using callbacks but since the output is in a Text field it doesn't seem to work. onChangeText doesn't recognize when text is changed in a text field? I've also tried using the callback on the Textinput but that doesn't seem to work either. Maybe I'm setting state in the wrong place.

Is this possible?

Child.js

```
getDLScore(e) {
    let i;
    i = deadliftScore.scoreSheet[e];

    if (e != '') {
      if (this.props.mosLevel === '1') {
        if (e <= 180) {
          return 'fail';
        } else {
          if (this.state.dlPoints != i) {
            this.setState({ dlPoints: i });
          }
          return i;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.eventContainer}>
          <View styles={styles.child2}>
            <Deadlift2
              textChange={dlScoreInput => this.setState({ dlScoreInput })}
            />
          </View>
          <View styles={styles.child3}>
            <Text style={styles.titleName}>Points</Text>
            <Text style={styles.output}>

              {this.getDLScore(this.state.dlScoreInput)} 
              // I want to pass this to my parent component

            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

const Deadlift2 = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={dlScoreInput => props.textChange(dlScoreInput)}
        value={props.dlScoreInput}
        onKeyPress={props.getDLScore}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Parent.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.screen2}>
         <Text>Points - {this.state.dlScoreInput}</Text>
      <View>
```

Comment: Is `TextInput` a material-ui component? Can you link the docs? I haven't used react native, but in regular react the argument is an event object. Not the text itself.

Comment: @Andrew not a part of material-ui. Straight from react-native. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you forgot to pass down the prop `dlScoreInput` into `<Deadlift2/>`. The `value` is `props.dlScoreInput`, so add that

```
<Deadlift2
   textChange={dlScoreInput => this.setState({ dlScoreInput })}
   dlScoreInput={this.state.dlScoreInput}
/>
```

The other is that you're not propogating the change up to the parent. You can apply the exact same logic you have that passes the information back up from `<Deadlift2 />` to `<Child />`.

But at that point, you're passing data 2 levels up. After a certain point, you're better off using some type of global state management system (like redux). But if you're adamant about using local state every step of the way, I can show you how to write it.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see both ways of passing state, using local state and redux. I've only been using react-native for a week so this is all still very new to me.